# How do I create an if or while loop without "test" and use a "not" operator?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

If I do:

```
if grep someexpression somefile >/dev/null; then
   ...
fi
```

Things work fine.

To do a "not", I know I can do this (using [] which is the test command):

```
if [ '!' somecondition ] ; then
   ...
fi
```

A simple workaround:

```
grep someexpression somefile >/dev/null
if [ '!' $? ]; then
   ...
fi
```

But the above workaround won't work with a while loop, so then I need to write a function instead, which is annoying. How do I do a not with the grep thing above, the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if ! grep someexpression somefile >/dev/null; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that the space after `!` is mandatory, otherwise it will (try to) invoke history expansion.

Comment: Interesting. Last time I had this problem, I tried exactly that, and it said something like "no such event". But your example worked fine.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html - it's even an example in the docs. (Works in ksh too, but I not sure if it is valid POSIX shell syntax.)

Comment: You had history expansion enabled. That shouldn't be a problem in a script. I disable it interactively because it causes more problems than it's worth. @Mat It's POSIX. It hasn't been around forever but I doubt there are serious users of such shells still around (way pre-bash/korn bourne shells).

Comment: @Peter: You probably did not put a space between the `!` and `grep`. Without a space (on the command line), `!grep` will search your history for the last command starting with `grep`. With a space, it will work as a negation operator.